# I want to delete cell of collectionview from other viewcontroller(swift)

Tags: swift

Is it anyway to delete cell in collectionview from another view controller that i pass data from CollectionView Cell to another view controller.

I pass the data to another view controller by this way.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addViewController") as! addViewController
        vc.name = nameArr[indexPath.row]
        vc.image = imgArr[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Now I'm stuck on I don't know how to delete the cell from addViewController and after delete go back to the ViewController that have UICollectionView and reload it.

like Instagram App

Comment: By the way, as a matter of convention, class names like `AddViewController` should always start with upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One view controller should not be directly updating another view controller’s model and UIKit controls. The current view controller should take care of that. The current view controller should provide some mechanism such that the other view controller can request when this deletion should take place.

You can do this via a closure or via the delegate-protocol pattern. For example, if you wanted to use a closure, you could:

- Give the `AddViewController` a closure for deleting an object:

  ```
  class AddViewController: UICollectionViewController {
      var onDelete: (() -> Void)?
      ...
  }
  ```
- When you instantiate the view controller, set that closure:

  ```
  extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
          let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addViewController") as! AddViewController
          let item = indexPath.item
          vc.name = nameArr[item]
          vc.image = imgArr[item]
          vc.onDelete = { [weak self]  in
              self?.nameArr.remove(at: item)
              self?.imgArr.remove(at: item)
              collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
          }
          navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      }
  }
  ```
- When that view controller needs to inform the current view controller that it should delete that data, it would call that closure:

  ```
  class AddViewController: UICollectionViewController {
      ...

      @IBAction func didTapDeleteButton(_ sender: Any) {
          onDelete?()
      }
  }
  ```